# Python Requests Error 400 Browser Sent An Invalid Request

Tags: python, python-requests, web-crawler

I have very limited knowledge in web crawling/scraping and am trying to create a web crawler to this `URL`. However, when I try the usual printing of the response text from the server, I get this:

```
<html><body><h1>400 Bad request</h1>
Your browser sent an invalid request.
</body></html>
```

I don't think there's anything wrong with the code as it works on other websites I've tried it on. Was hoping you good folks here could help me figure this out. And this is just a hunch, but is this caused by the url not ending in a `.xml`?

```
import requests
url = 'https://phys.org/rss-feed/'
res = requests.get(url)
print(res.text[:500])
```

Comment: @JoshuaVarghese thank you! I've been trying to figure this out for days. But could you explain why it doesn't work with just the url alone?

Comment: I think the server dissalows bots https://phys.org/robots.txt

Comment: most domains have a robots.txt implementing restrictions on bots

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `BeautifulSoup` and a header to mask your request like a real one:

```
import requests,lxml
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
URL='https://phys.org/rss-feed/'
USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:65.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/65.0"
headers = {"user-agent": USER_AGENT}
resp = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.content, "lxml")
print(soup)
```

---

Just masking alone also works:

```
import requests
URL='https://phys.org/rss-feed/'
USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:65.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/65.0"
headers = {"user-agent": USER_AGENT}
resp = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)
```